# Ruby: how to round Time variable at midnight

Tags: ruby

in Ruby how can I round a Time viariable at midnight?

As an example how can I get the following Time variable:

```
2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC
```

From this one?

```
2020-01-07 02:33:01 UTC
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. In what way you want to do the rounding? One time stamp is midnight, the other one is half past two in the morning. And, are you talking about the strings you posted, or are you talking about objects of class `Time`, or of class `Date` or of class `DateTime`.

Comment: What are you rounding rules? A conditional should do what you need.

Comment: I've downvoted your question, not just because it is unclear, but mainly because you have refused to clarify it despite two members asking you to do so (which is also disrespectful to them and to SO generally). I will retract my downvote if you clarify with an edit.

Comment: Analogous to `2.6.round #=> 3` and `2.6.truncate #=> 2`, if I'm asked to *round* a time to midnight I would select the *closest* midnight, not the latest midnight on or before the given time. Please edit to clarify what you mean by "round".

Comment: The question is poorly asked. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you could convert to Time to date.

```
Time.now.to_date.to_time
```

Comment: The question gives you a `Time` object to modify. Why are you disregarding that and using `Time.now`? This gives the time at the previous midnight (unless the given time is midnight, in which that time is returned). The question does not define "round"; it could be the previous midnight or the closest midnight.

Comment: Note that this will produce 00:00:00 in the current time zone. `Time.utc(2020, 1, 7, 2, 33, 1).to_date.to_time #=> 2020-01-07 00:00:00 +0100`

Answer (score 4):

Once created, `Time` instances cannot be modified. You have to create a *new* instance, e.g. given:

```
require 'time'

t = Time.parse('2020-01-07 02:33:01 UTC')
#=> 2020-01-07 02:33:01 UTC
```

You could call [`Time.utc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Time.html#method-c-utc) passing the object's year, month and day:

```
Time.utc(t.year, t.month, t.day)
#=> 2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: First adjust `t` if the idea is to round to the nearest midnight: `t += 12*60*60`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the question leaves room for interpretation. I thought the OP just wanted to set hours, minutes, and seconds to 0. More examples or a better explanation would help.

Comment: The question is poorly asked and needs to be clarified. Answering before that's been done results in confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using *ActiveSupport* you can use [`Time#change`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change).

```
time_1 = Time.utc(2020, 1, 7, 2, 33, 1)
time_2 = time_1.change(hour: 0, min: 0, sec: 0)
#=> 2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC
```

Or [`Time#midnight`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-midnight)/[`Time#beginning_of_day`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-beginning_of_day) like Stefan pointed out in the comments.

```
time_2 = time_1.beginning_of_day
#=> 2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: Or `time_1.midnight`

Answer (score 0):

While this question is quite unclear, just incase anyone ends up here looking (like I was) for something that will map any time to the closest midnight (i.e. **pre-midday to previous midnight**, and **post-midday to next midnight**), then this should work:

`time = Time.parse("2020-01-07 02:33:01 UTC")` (using the example given in the question)

```
if time.hour >= 12 # any time after midday
  time.end_of_day
else
  time.beginning_of_day
end
```